# NUKE expression references top level Camera

Tags: python, xml, tcl, nuke

I have gizmoB that takes a camera as input. GizmoB lives in GizmoA which also takes a camera as input. I want gizmoB to be able to access the camera via an expression. However nothing I do quite seems to work. The XML-script might better explain it.

Basically `Camera` -> `GizmoA` -> `GizmoB`.

Thanks for your help. Maybe I'm going at this the wrong way, it's been a while since I have used Nuke and Python.

```
#! C:/Program Files/Nuke10.0v3/nuke-10.0.3.dll -nx
version 10.0 v3
define_window_layout_xml {<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <window x="0" y="0" w="1920" h="848" screen="0">
        <splitter orientation="1">
            <split size="40"/>
            <dock id="" hideTitles="1" activePageId="Toolbar.1">
                <page id="Toolbar.1"/>
            </dock>
            <split size="1241" stretch="1"/>
            <splitter orientation="2">
                <split size="287"/>
                <dock id="" activePageId="Viewer.2">
                    <page id="Viewer.2"/>
                    <page id="Viewer.1"/>
                </dock>
                <split size="495"/>
                <dock id="" activePageId="DAG.2">
                    <page id="DAG.1"/>
                    <page id="Curve Editor.1"/>
                    <page id="DopeSheet.1"/>
                    <page id="DAG.2"/>
                </dock>
            </splitter>
            <split size="615"/>
            <dock id="" activePageId="Properties.1" focus="true">
                <page id="Properties.1"/>
            </dock>
        </splitter>
    </window>
</layout>
}
Root {
 inputs 0
 name Q:/data/test.nk
 title "sq2600 s1 - nuke_scripts.nk"
 frame 2
 last_frame 96
 lock_range true
 colorManagement Nuke
 views {
  {LFT ""}
  {RGT ""}
 }
 addUserKnob {20 User}
 addUserKnob {1 lt_res}
 lt_res "\$\{a_res\}"
 addUserKnob {1 mp_res}
 mp_res 1
 addUserKnob {1 fx_res}
 fx_res "\$\{a_res\}"
 addUserKnob {1 mpaint_res +INVISIBLE}
 addUserKnob {1 lighting_res +INVISIBLE}
 addUserKnob {4 deptMode l "Choose a department mode:" M {none "Image Finaling" Layout Lighting FX}}
}
Camera2 {
 inputs 0
 read_from_file true
 rot_order XYZ
 translate {2.836216927 8.794775009 13.20492458}
 rotate {-17.39999962 22.20000076 7.170989063e-014}
 focal 35
 haperture 35.99992752
 vaperture 23.99995222
 near 0.1000000015
 far 25
 file camera1.fbx
 fbx_node_name {{7} "Producer Perspective" "Producer Top" "Producer Bottom" "Producer Front" "Producer Back" "Producer Right" "Producer Left" camera1}
 name Camera1
 xpos 1333
 ypos 5163
}
set N5363c00 [stack 0]
Read {
 inputs 0
 file ../images/test.%04d.exr
 format "1024 768 0 0 1024 768 1 "
 last 96
 origlast 96
 origset true
 name Read1
 xpos 1156
 ypos 5213
}
set N3ac68800 [stack 0]
Group {
 inputs 2
 name GizmoC
 label "(\[value space_transform])"
 selected true
 xpos 1449
 ypos 5282
 addUserKnob {20 SpaceTransform}
 addUserKnob {26 info l "" +STARTLINE T "Connect camera for transformation"}
 addUserKnob {26 ""}
 addUserKnob {41 in l input T Shuffle1.in}
 addUserKnob {4 data_type l "data type" M {"normal vectors" "point positions"}}
 data_type "point positions"
 addUserKnob {4 space_transform l "space transform" M {"cam to world" "world to cam" ""}}
 space_transform "world to cam"
 addUserKnob {41 out l output T ShuffleCopy1.out2}
 addUserKnob {26 ""}
}
 Input {
  inputs 0
  name cam
  xpos 852
  ypos -563
  number 1
 }
 Axis2 {
  name Axis3
  xpos 862
  ypos -489
 }
 NoOp {
  name NoOp1
  label "camera scale"
  xpos 852
  ypos -399
  addUserKnob {20 User}
  addUserKnob {13 scale}
  scale {{"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].scaling.x]"} {"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].scaling.y]"} {"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].scaling.z]"}}
  addUserKnob {7 uniform_scale l "uniform scale"}
  uniform_scale {{"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].uniform_scale]"}}
  addUserKnob {13 total_scale l "total scale"}
  total_scale {{"scale*uniform_scale ? 1/(scale*uniform_scale) : 0"} {"scale*uniform_scale ? 1/(scale*uniform_scale) : 0"} {"scale*uniform_scale ? 1/(scale*uniform_scale) : 0"}}
 }
 Input {
  inputs 0
  name src
  xpos 164
  ypos -564
 }
 Dot {
  name Dot7
  xpos 198
  ypos -482
 }
set N59756400 [stack 0]
 Shuffle {
  in rgb
  alpha black
  out rgb
  name Shuffle1
  label "in: \[value in]"
  xpos 400
  ypos -489
 }
 Dot {
  name Dot1
  xpos 434
  ypos -397
 }
set N529ffc00 [stack 0]
 Dot {
  name Dot2
  xpos 666
  ypos -397
 }
 Add {
  channels rgb
  value {{-parent.Axis3.world_matrix.3} {-parent.Axis3.world_matrix.7} {-parent.Axis3.world_matrix.11} 0}
  name Add1
  label "inverse translation"
  xpos 632
  ypos -246
  disable {{!parent.data_type}}
 }
 ColorMatrix {
  matrix {
      {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.0 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.1 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.2 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
      {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.4 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.5 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.6 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
      {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.8 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.9 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.10 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
    }
  invert true
  name ColorMatrix3
  label "world to cam"
  xpos 632
  ypos -184
  disable {{hasError}}
 }
 Dot {
  name Dot3
  xpos 666
  ypos -77
 }
push $N529ffc00
 ColorMatrix {
  matrix {
      {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.0 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.1 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.2 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
      {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.4 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.5 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.6 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
      {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.8 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.9 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.10 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
    }
  name ColorMatrix2
  label "cam to world"
  xpos 400
  ypos -310
  disable {{hasError}}
 }
 Add {
  channels rgb
  value {{parent.Axis3.world_matrix.3} {parent.Axis3.world_matrix.7} {parent.Axis3.world_matrix.11} 0}
  name Add5
  label translation
  xpos 400
  ypos -246
  disable {{!parent.data_type}}
 }
 Switch {
  inputs 2
  which {{parent.space_transform}}
  name Switch1
  label transform
  xpos 400
  ypos -84
 }
push $N59756400
 ShuffleCopy {
  inputs 2
  alpha alpha2
  black red
  white green
  red2 blue
  green2 alpha
  out2 rgb
  name ShuffleCopy1
  label "out: \[value out2]"
  xpos 164
  ypos -84
  disable {{"!(NoOp1.total_scale.x && NoOp1.total_scale.y && NoOp1.total_scale.z && \[exists parent.input0])"}}
 }
 Output {
  name Output1
  xpos 164
  ypos 9
 }
end_group
Viewer {
 frame_range 1-96
 name Viewer1
 xpos 1449
 ypos 5211
}
push $N5363c00
push $N3ac68800
push 0
Group {
 inputs 3
 name gizmoA
 tile_color 0x5f5f5fff
 note_font "Bitstream Vera Sans"
 note_font_size 14
 note_font_color 0xfefefeff
 xpos 1156
 ypos 5380
}
 Output {
  inputs 0
  name Output
  xpos -1040
  ypos -504
 }
 Input {
  inputs 0
  name shot_cam
  label "\[value number]"
  xpos -901
  ypos -930
  number 2
 }
 Input {
  inputs 0
  name position
  label "\[value number]"
  xpos -1116
  ypos -935
  number 1
 }
 Group {
  inputs 2
  name GizmoB
  label "(\[value space_transform])"
  selected true
  xpos -958
  ypos -826
  addUserKnob {20 SpaceTransform}
  addUserKnob {26 info l "" +STARTLINE T "Connect camera for transformation"}
  addUserKnob {26 ""}
  addUserKnob {41 in l input T Shuffle1.in}
  addUserKnob {4 data_type l "data type" M {"normal vectors" "point positions"}}
  data_type "point positions"
  addUserKnob {4 space_transform l "space transform" M {"cam to world" "world to cam" ""}}
  space_transform "world to cam"
  addUserKnob {41 out l output T ShuffleCopy1.out2}
  addUserKnob {26 ""}
 }
  Input {
   inputs 0
   name cam
   xpos 852
   ypos -563
   number 1
  }
  Axis2 {
   name Axis3
   xpos 862
   ypos -489
  }
  NoOp {
   name NoOp1
   label "camera scale"
   xpos 852
   ypos -399
   addUserKnob {20 User}
   addUserKnob {13 scale}
   scale {{"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].scaling.x]"} {"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].scaling.y]"} {"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].scaling.z]"}}
   addUserKnob {7 uniform_scale l "uniform scale"}
   uniform_scale {{"\[value \[topnode parent.input1].uniform_scale]"}}
   addUserKnob {13 total_scale l "total scale"}
   total_scale {{"scale*uniform_scale ? 1/(scale*uniform_scale) : 0"} {"scale*uniform_scale ? 1/(scale*uniform_scale) : 0"} {"scale*uniform_scale ? 1/(scale*uniform_scale) : 0"}}
  }
  Input {
   inputs 0
   name src
   xpos 164
   ypos -564
  }
  Dot {
   name Dot7
   xpos 198
   ypos -482
  }
set N374e8c00 [stack 0]
  Shuffle {
   in rgb
   alpha black
   out rgb
   name Shuffle1
   label "in: \[value in]"
   xpos 400
   ypos -489
  }
  Dot {
   name Dot1
   xpos 434
   ypos -397
  }
set N25e1bc00 [stack 0]
  Dot {
   name Dot2
   xpos 666
   ypos -397
  }
  Add {
   channels rgb
   value {{-parent.Axis3.world_matrix.3} {-parent.Axis3.world_matrix.7} {-parent.Axis3.world_matrix.11} 0}
   name Add1
   label "inverse translation"
   xpos 632
   ypos -246
   disable {{!parent.data_type}}
  }
  ColorMatrix {
   matrix {
       {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.0 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.1 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.2 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
       {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.4 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.5 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.6 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
       {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.8 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.9 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.10 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
     }
   invert true
   name ColorMatrix3
   label "world to cam"
   xpos 632
   ypos -184
   disable {{hasError}}
  }
  Dot {
   name Dot3
   xpos 666
   ypos -77
  }
push $N25e1bc00
  ColorMatrix {
   matrix {
       {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.0 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.1 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.2 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
       {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.4 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.5 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.6 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
       {{"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.8 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.9 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.y"} {"parent.Axis3.world_matrix.10 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.z"}}
     }
   name ColorMatrix2
   label "cam to world"
   xpos 400
   ypos -310
   disable {{hasError}}
  }
  Add {
   channels rgb
   value {{parent.Axis3.world_matrix.3} {parent.Axis3.world_matrix.7} {parent.Axis3.world_matrix.11} 0}
   name Add5
   label translation
   xpos 400
   ypos -246
   disable {{!parent.data_type}}
  }
  Switch {
   inputs 2
   which {{parent.space_transform}}
   name Switch1
   label transform
   xpos 400
   ypos -84
  }
push $N374e8c00
  ShuffleCopy {
   inputs 2
   alpha alpha2
   black red
   white green
   red2 blue
   green2 alpha
   out2 rgb
   name ShuffleCopy1
   label "out: \[value out2]"
   xpos 164
   ypos -84
   disable {{"!(NoOp1.total_scale.x && NoOp1.total_scale.y && NoOp1.total_scale.z && \[exists parent.input0])"}}
  }
  Output {
   name Output1
   xpos 164
   ypos 9
  }
 end_group
end_group
```

Answer (score 0):

For this script I turned off `read from fbx file` option and then manually animated a `Camera1`.

Patrick, I see you turned on an inversion of values in `ColorMatrix1` and `ColorMatrix3` which leads to errors in case you have zeros inside RGB matrix (because all three main diagonal values of your `ColorMatrix` nodes equal to `0`).

[image]

You've written an expression inside `NoOp1` node (this expression affects `ColorMatrix` node):

```
parent.Axis3.world_matrix.0 * parent.NoOp1.total_scale.x
```

**The expression itself is OK** but the default values of `scale` and `uniform scale` properties can't be `0` – they must be `+1` (suitable for visible RGB spectrum) or even `-1` (suitable for invisible PP spectrum – negative color values are quite usual in NUKE, especially for such render passes as Point Position). Thus, your conditional expression based on ternary operator for `total scale` property in `NoOp1` node is incorrect:

```
scale * uniform_scale ? 1/(scale * uniform_scale) : 0    // INCORRECT EXPRESSION
```

So your expression must be, at least, like the following:

```
scale * uniform_scale ? abs(1/(scale * uniform_scale)) : 1
```

Even if `if-statement` doesn't work you'll get default `1` value for scaling in `else-statement`.

The values in `scale` and `uniform scale` knobs equal to `0` because you should assign the right name of an input for top node (the syntax of TCL-expression itself is also OK):

```
[value [topnode parent.Camera1].scaling.x]
[value [topnode parent.Camera1].scaling.y]
[value [topnode parent.Camera1].scaling.z]

[value [topnode parent.Camera1].uniform_scale]
```

or:

```
[value [topnode parent.input1].scaling.x]    // Axis node has 'input0' and 'input1'
[value [topnode parent.input1].scaling.y]
[value [topnode parent.input1].scaling.y]

[value [topnode parent.input1].uniform_scale]
```

Also, I've noticed that you have errors in both expressions in `Switch1` and `Switch2` nodes. The expression inside `Switch1` node looks like this:

```
parent.space_transform                                 // NO 'space_transform' HERE
```

But, as you can see, this expression leads to an error as well (I don't see any `space_transform` property in your NUKE script at all):

[image]

**So I fixed all the aforementioned errors and now script perfectly works**.

> **Play this GIF sequence by clicking it**.

[image]

> I can share only encrypted XML code of a working script. So for reading it in you need The Foundry NUKE 11.3v1 **Non-commercial Edition**. Here's my code (copy-paste this very long string):

```
Nuke NC mode encrypted text (commercial mode uses plain text)     Qg[dmPBB4Y\H8h8hGFegl_d1o14fK4hX8:9H6ETYjE^K7W6[^S]CWHCF<<STTjcZY9R9W6nWjeX47>A`23OdUB>D<16l4nFd][?OQmGMAa2?:RDV8CRNhV6jYAkc\1^b0d9ZWC7JXAJGY43<_k?8a;AbOmh3Z^IU4LnKLdFo?7nif>XVIJOmbX1F2LK4VaQ07?Fg<YcLW<_:ocje@A32AT]Y9iO@jh<ic3oO8_VQH576G6[3SA]e45LPn=d5<?;l]>J6U4O6KKSGN47V^1Oj4;C;gKf@[M`>:J]WOIfH3A<LYkM?83fPBGXCL718:_nIY8Xe?`7_?2hiQU0jXSY8nI=EgAB`[]YCYmCKo9KDKY?QTBY=:6E5_R[Ra[1AkFa>LLdC\Hic[1fiinmU]1;4dcKMF7bSoInH1Pj71la>=8A<^jBQob2>Y6R1kbLN0R=^O0f`DjNOmn6jDCC5Q>3KY_AlAgAG4Qhbk_1XHL1`h]BlL0Uk;7RCLODK=hd2V0QXiii04G_IQle?J\e6EIIoCenL64li\F>n:7Q_l2Q@L=Ee4j]C`;bHh:m2;[hf:N74lVUe7=Xkj^bG1_M:PZMBi]RQSlHMQWTW?UPAQlIV9BKbb9ABN`]4d[QQ:Ccmn=[BVoJN82@E3]jdE=[3[Xgi8nI@UbTncRmChX4g<=5CnooKBdgSZWjWOdEJW;jR2:Y:9]Y:EM7LEZlRkQH@5;h6iORc09LN[DaAQ25>MO`HJBm6>[B5IDT[0JL6AHchP\j3B_`XLD]kM?2B=74g842GF]B557iQ@LEE;[Jb<0JWKFXdgNK903C^;1GlSA:kRi1W8k:\OWH__c@f[=SBG8M9FOkNAD5\>Clki0lP]`YG4ilR2`IigPK]E^h>IYW95:W8k2OiGChFG?KYPbQ6OiR2APll8<mS0VHdc87_o\KckPIjR`b1JWaf_W?Fn\:AMDGeL9EPS:CXb0>;0WG^a@10gf>`TUlEVdb@Uh8MZ6FTcHa]NDBalEW\YA:]O`H8eNQ=i8@3jT1LmiALF:3QZLQV:i9UMce52Z\8<XO4?HC=RA31`BScn@Y1EJ5^e[XG`nm69HhkAeBXF=[_O6_BdW<>>:7b9`NaUGnUITL9Ig7jh@T9hkE8Y?nmIncfeI7RI`X6e@8ie6@b9^je0Dj[Eg>oeI?RFg6M\h`JO;EZKXlWo`L6X8O\VW>YALO\=caIh6KNK>i8_8X=0XS^T@^H5VNHO`LDkLGhk]JJXn[3j0?9NUYnS`;km8MLf=5i\G=[8BZ>aV9Fgi@I@YS1LBYb<]Wb[9BZ0a^39EHMcUJ\nD;hP>:B6QeJe^N_H@7UWcm1nBXMfnGIkD_600HUmL;iUV@@U5J6X><k7@Qm8EVJWAIMocno>m`36b74LQL:dbcES0KP<nCfMoJaCYQEM;i_T_Jh0TL=^RkC4C<R=a_6haaEDM825XjLgYh8OhBik]GK88EQg?hh\AlRE2LU`JKfiIXXRB;Ag0>:Yjn8_S[GUTB>`l8X@GNN\R<CSkGc[F4`YZG>QUJIh8]C\KR93>QMQKC>PKWngHdEX@K@C89a0FL1>DoT:RSBcc=HhCD`>D_=C_58B^dj?N<B;]]W_nFla]k\AcS>Hnf>nk0oNUFYgMg2dXOL5n>FjV9B12@:@]S]W[=_FQ01jmU^dl\SfG@`J41hMYSbo1gmF]HmM6GnnQi^_]fNnfLiecM60m^i\V>`G\?VUB`4FdZeg8dn[ABOOaFdcT23b2CnSQlfo2Pj^o5Kgj[BlOhlaRV]3f\h^jb1Mc9Gi5]e>^?HiDDBYMd<6AD2E<aRETWcNPJQ]]Io`KB1Wdj]gg=]O]=FF^ak6AbJaJ4k]:XnX14SYoJeRdHDFOU;mV\ao>BY0>@N@YEh:1=nUV46TN67g2E]1lm4RnkhKUiX6`DTaZignFnmO4i:8QXcHVcJj`dHRFcR\lFTMg6PZ??P4?WLRR254c_L:QVG<i=2jNOnT15nF0ae:_10RI9SlF6mC:m;>4g]LDPoMW:[Eo?l7S;dZR8Q9=C>5H`i:QO`6OJHY5O:PhYNfbdYM21XCWidNNjHLCiJeHB\<fL_1?`N@TJCjNlFPbQ]Jbeo0CE:Lfa=XBaXRMS>2AXZkI?dMoDP84BThoa`[HlWZmnPAFifhgdd?DSC2okIJJ2e^WiJ@m5IM@j[:1TQJC<]\P34>>=ZeNCZPcH;h5AU312C4K:Y<4bB3LY3h^9?]jVVW]7\mgo4Ck4fKgA:DA1?4^J=X[cU8j6Y8G]UIT7X4KkHU75N`9l1jFmQ2lleg8<d70WILeWX;5K4OO]<D^D_@X:``<Ggl>[_W>PCABdSh^?;2JQNP@8FN3DjGRbKid6hB0oQ1@6KXM8KW1WYO^F]Ch@?8fGMGh7am=SDK4>9?Ll?\nQ:bX8FVKXZT_gHQbi]>_:;9okH_n=ceGZ?HgnGN]4FZn[7^fZ=kC02lV0BZ79Uh\12C]1NS5FC<4BM=mY6lUiCim^Qd5`9STZ5?4:HaM^=]`c8i8PP\Sn<@T7C`6k7`CkB6KLm57D^oXC[2eB5B_Rfjn>Z@GaAMJhBbDjN0`<HoKjn<aXJKGV4k2K\2Y2E<K_LOF8;`j7o43[2ZM5h<O\L8c_0`4GKDHWNMV4OSWEH4RMnCh\3F=>1O:]kN4SJVYiES?F;JMmV?F7UdcX79@nD<VD563k?D4E>ol\bZiIS6jhM[H3k0J[hHR7Z:>Lbf@F4Q=>B6[KV>f1`BC?HIhVU?\g0U4Lo;G;2GXBe9>6IQQ=OnIma0N8k]hd;Snh44HI[W6]Co`lS_3Y7`2Gj@9e2K@:LcU^<M8HnKV8jgc[b>M:=bjcN8CkBSb1cZUC53bK944bn]mdHP\ThF8d9dGDao:[:Ri0_70<fO8hXR;ee0:HaBD^ZeKHCPaOF1<93WoQcbNa??Aaan]GX_:P^i68R2bccWa>QDVJ\bCY:0O:k6E7a>@VjP=gkgZ=7nNWo=jJ@j^BSdc<F;T96k<ZNNR1F?77DOUM_Z=5:TQ85iFlemgSW?V;Jl=mEXX@PdfgJ2aFJ\HF[BU6TWd;aa@dN:Z\8Hi@>`1Z36YWW?\Y\j[i`O@efo3[c1Lb8[9J6ekde<1BK3@0Y>3eV6M?ChTGn\@U8<gH6]L7g^j8=f7cH@3mK7D@g?99VTNZ]Ti>TZ3@7_TTo_2K[QQ?_WMS6X]F_YZVVf?QoaZK4nj9b0K1f7=KA2`QdFOeC1>2TTceQLnBBShjBbWL_5S;WlKHBOF:GLHkcUTG\3?CQVZh;kc^>o=X6Q9\b:F1cmC?EOZQ:;D8c7g`SSE[UHCe9TU2c;^;BmgXP4`SHZWPBU1R@R7e6XI;MDiSVH9FkWc\^P111cU6cLmBHJP1JY`dU4hdXROX5<>eP5:6YKJRhi>Ad:@n>fQYHEbD47[FUYM67F4O<5E92IO[KVbJ<DI3D66@bao4LS1CiMJm546<V9JaE[FN4Tal1Yn`0DI4ND2Z3Ygk717;VS:nZ9@?GCVHPdOd?oQ>WJlh3<hb@a[0YfG?WHKIHf_cZg?eJcSEj[9W5;ETW;2W2[>30>JEA3S0?@ZVkM:Z?f\b1CK204FM1WC5PYGj==\HHNWkf<M69IKgHW4B\aVK@M_C5li]:k360fFDB@Mi@VRkeMk4<IQf2F;BgWO7YA8AgIV]n?aDPTWTGi@8Lb6Ff6S7gR:WEjWPn^lDaDJeYK\d_YYjn=A4iYlkh`C<P^i`V6LKU32aEF4OOn0_bgMBh:L`EI[3GeP0W:KDIB=2>C\8co7CQB;fjXoD0NbL]ZYn_>iiNZ3kVn6]I\hS@GQP35:[0N?iO6D_:\SB1NbXm6=VQ9Ec>Lh0Y=`m<:;cKT5CDAjd^NCI]0>doHSl^XhOVP5TCZgiA1V]2aNQ\Z]EKgKbR:?X\NndNlmOP^4cZllW8ieVROfkK2:Jd_JTcJBohQ]kcCO9K8C@bL_QbSYQm:X37VRlf?;nMl_\:;o3bkSQj>HUm[6jH@AN1eHQWZSjiKQ>O\Nncje=f]k2HP4oX;ljdU2T=6icAA43EAR=`j:<U\c7JP8NIT_44ZeTdCL9k^0jgZ\\g1IIEGVO;@L@X3fVW?QeGGbG_H6:N4;m_Ol\6nBd90e>M9cEHRWI3:Y6\7MK1BRRACHSfR?ib8lL6A;[OBRSliN\IjMASOKCaH;Ko<HZd:<He]k>R9D8K]PR>f?RGjeb[Dm><UTR_0oS;@^]2mNBOZP`mg@2Qo?ha0e32o]ZMOeg3?Q;bJ0<1k\<h\LEGk5>4n<9VJIlA>9YA?S0UN4<^Ih9e\R[ilH5MhdVnce65eR3HiQ6PWnF_CNJBN:4]bUSDKIeGhVoYVZ;2IM3NT8k^95G^Zn^LadXkP]h:P?;PZ37AP_EMVEPKSgo_MH37^3Z[YmK_IncY>7;Ajb;^D4d`YUIAAbnRL3T_94WHc?IW\Nj]3OiLb707@f?SAV:3]SFo]Y77a53\RSmd2Nb645\Fke^2?T82G:edc3Vi4?kW;WKBgM<R]LLUiAicigX1O^1Mn463@Zd==\nl];>]b1h?Rf28Q[^hPoAAk:LC6PU3nEB=FMcWoN:AMj]Se[C=me9^Zhf:YHZGcEcZ80Ac4G;ZnDOL0bbbC=F5A`9QdPYV2j:e7hCb3G[AS[Q51QBM1MUocTFF4GSB_6P1Qk43L_XPcGed[2W38n?VRhcFNMK9e>O10e^h4nQZD=SNS^V]2eHPNXd;h744`4d;B]KT;KH5f^=oIAZA?`J6abR;HLMFU?8cEgLI=Dn`k>1T\GGTT0oSHQmLPT[7Kf:6;hUMm5WRn4KbOO]^>mne^8CO4:eRDM18KgK0dNYmN[d^n6M7aB:mhiAm20[fSo=\ga8boVjF?DTJ9Z?Bb3;X[ldk0oDfgDAP;B=WLM]oEnbD\^H_YHHKRYhCL_oH;oc3FgVTaFEgCTdmcd]I<S6]^1[m1jZnIa<CbZn;D3EX];c=97:QF0SOega\kej=i7@aSieO=_1Q42Y78n2;NYNTac<cd4;V];KCANUo?jW>Ua8en?W@ZZH4>TS]XI<C_g\08_^W6UI6IkE7DX<[FO5n2S4a@2X2ZcAa76\ZeVFL;jnb82HdP1=m]kRl[^EGkV1F<JPI3ZD^RB\M45YS\6VQ=n2Rj1]]9iQh349mAcHEf0:2\0`M:@RSPSHKio68deTmd=R82YPhcd7l0f:jdi>6WXggTmSM:bZblkKOo89PPMc8oHFXY_=BJK<<g6_E1P8=8UQSlUXX0gXGgL:MY@nn4aO?Wg37l]N]Vck7[R17UTH\KJK:b6T10:Bhj\=SaaZ7OHgUKd31CT52ko4Wm?2iI2VI3D9NGAUA;1ATS_JP1O?VdojAT:5PLlIelBQ<LVnWhaF2Nm^77DhoPPCPe<_Z3_02Ef]2o=JNdDZkH>MAF^aIl5BUG]ZH=\`W`koghEcgke4_<Od2=\jT@SE:FJGa3D[d[Cf>beX6gfT5Tg2VkBj_Z\X[>B;ha=_=\78?o`lB2ocbF82Ad_CMW9LSRV4g;Z[Ci;V7]j7E_S2fTl0A61f2\Dh5<hK\a<\\2A4daiZFJNfM9A0Jhhfd^FSGPOHNlh<\d:dj<@10bN70LmjLG48FLZ>WTN9SgFMgOMlRa@O_D=Z;]=>UR=RHNEAMES?<<A_i^DYl2]9W:334j27iAgkKee=0:mAS\LB;eO44Xg>gema`FXB\JeKdkJjfcMMXQMeWe13GY7CWR>4B65k[nh>QJcZQbUA<Xg\Gnj?[`?gR4NeOS8V@Wi2FVhD8:ZdJ5mTP\5j\WRRdgn]PeX;4<=WQ5TBS?<m:7ZQRBI0E^KiOOF3g:e;kmW=G>KSeFXd:LoXE5=GgMf3HH\icNi[?R4LVCXRK0>11cg0>KiO50N54aTUQn_:keDi=<3\8_E@SUbmYAbU1:J@H:o:A>>ETKE0R69_]eA188HQZaVW[`i0=ck6i=ZPFTF?^7H@efcoddedi9h8am2O215kZVM=[VP6eh27Q[6Uo7O4e4cOg?DK6D@1f>]NTH8YVKjJfabZBVlc=?KB?5Ffc9Wd1<:GVfgDW]CMFFV2mghfmfUB53iG\DP:Qc]mIT>GKQ;AbRZ[B^ck4j60aY>bVh:QPU^O:Lb\`0PMc;4H[H]:hEi_d8[Y@biGDFn7kR=_>PeX_W[JD1`ZEM_fd^LBT>QoDm1B]PSN5fZJgCmL\XYY8TMokje8bij1^PD<eFP6C<9l>2Tn`hj:39DO26gjaC^RT883_WO>8JKZZg_DFodGiBPL4OE^jYn[UkH0QNB<KCSbFTbGda3lk`FbRLUe4=CddKbLAaR6PM>R:c;gXLDQccT0cBN:Z]1Vc[Gf>1J>YF9V`@BEJfgRZb;JQ8?>GgY=M<@Km1XPBfohj@]9eX:JD`>5]Y9:;d@KX9DVT0dM08A@R`A0hHY[lnVXVkaSU5LiJ@EmdQWnl4dFOWV0J4CLOU\<gLJbJOC=Znil19moaVc[acV9D82RmEY^od37TFlnef1KMNASdb;KEFa4MH?IYfchMG6SgG1IH@jfnAWdN2VHU05^`8`fVbAm67WdVUooVP\mE7if<J;dL>SR4^:hRCSi5e>>_ChMfS6Df<U1cJ?b;PYTi4NTcm];UD7<QiN^S8>C2_N[DYh[QT\omlkSO^TfCaJcRLGoYYND;Je0I3TnRPI;]BCFk<KA_93N@Nge?dSK?oGNP;@c_:mIUhYk6X@<YCLlYX4DRX8AR\n:Nl0KF6OlZmmY8YcC7Zb\j2:;IeQ7PBJ<7m<TV[Ra=4<`88B`J8=A5Oh;QUgdZ_416KlioKC@Oa]_oA4]3N`YHjX7omML5SOKeHN0o<URI:2FQ8:_mVTFM:L[L@R66ZL1PPa83:KY]`S0n8ojNBNg@j02nVZFhVA;MJmm4nX5BFXch5L[A5fbdbOXG=U2PGWFR\`KUje`KUBd[TmN1U\lP\\=LO=2B[95QC]2AB\C^NP<E1ToYZ>YV:o=\_XH?9k7Qo1=VSo<hk`]:n0M7bXk3=F06E3`XEN:cWEe36BhIaJTFV8^=N]HBGLP4lNDiiU^F@NBCoO=H2iUOK:\YV8cZhn>>e;3HUG07DY_c@EG^CP7OiblG?2g[gC;?lgJK?TFmD8j0oDj?OXPPoO\oQK>]GEimT=hB>iC;5^73_<I>9<1cj4[\6mkKHcNlQ9k>L9L72?<HNh0G1H\FI@Wd0H;i`[^hHdiCGWSGn8\<iQiDhhJJjWD=\3PO?1mA8880g2RFMNSDLa:4B92BOf>o7P<fC@@XFj4;6CfGSU]=hRcgHWo:U;QM?cd_IKhhD^7_dbc2Jao4FMT`<=SFdO^6gQkg<QoT4=n3UI3HQg\GG@8WhGmZ>ABP7[6QLkRiQ[16a1^MELI0FX4oL2Sm67^I\2a4kP@ESn2e6nLiL0_]VJlk:fmgR[kWGk\GB62lBT2E;TALIO;;@Hfa:JA63QZUS54[EXb@6Xo8U:HIl7=>F^Gk\Z2MfCdA[0F7Bj?nHo?_EgD?015PJ75oC0hkB3jjM536_0O4ocW\TV;=Bmg^Na5fff8@5IN\RLlEDmj\J5NdW1f]8[]MW5T9TZ83_njg5;cBY@jmghhF>d?6L^[KX2TU:cm8a_@hk:1[O9iHZO:Z[kR^N5dO^NZbVYBj]6KV`3MLac:Iih46i^j@m[3V635M6`4YQn`3Cl^`>C:HaG37Sd1im6aTDAVn9E?8YA;HVPe<OIEKiHC0Y36D>9XkjadJj3EgIM;o]ZAikaFYhL5;?>6]>3de6`o[XRRelL:NGF9@^Ph8Wb6CBP>Jb;Sk_B1`68BKQZXALfl=daa:^eEn7VW4Ne5\a^@_`hI_fe8]jkXb=KcQ<jV:cS\XSHiE?>Yg=E7XFhVXU8=6m7h1XB=lV3@=38c8bI_@gMULc8CK:?5V33;^kAA9TK[L<1QjCGae=md5?ZFmdPBYgP\4`VTBV0GZCCdRdBgkY][24LEmgJ843bLOMV9<RR^ooVZ25Sonk@]GmkIJ_KMW<J0ghle3cQZPP1_lCnnfENCbVa[UdcPY>A7C09_4?:`Ui<XB<h^_>f146o9a5KmTC?<jNJ2?a_A8;nj;H6ddgRfcD^`W<b@mVanSJYg^jcmKBkQ2Ta`H4X3Vl?_Zf13XY;8?]gFQj6;K_4J=\95WEFC?:`^TXJX;Lc@kQDXUQak4OjW]=0\fTD]4NR4=U::fHl]i_K>Se:FZ1BU6lY?WVJ5Nf5abDeeM??0KN5:ELgVKM4WO=DjNmgfd1]M;<<fiEEocSJAfJ1]>Dcg_gc6:1K`:<KO9l553fL[9FPQ4cTn\UGLgCIA1;N\IoNmOJ@UblaTg\QVaiLT?heEf]A>;eec5<cn<<3AXIH:>TZo]0llOU_\n8=A0YZB;6O<Jg7ZM]aNPVK69hl]>2BY1XEX2Il_LDhNbc>aTE3>^2=>DG>AIi]85T8fZ>`dI1aW[3CbQlZH[XSgOIkSTAJ4FjgJ11dZ3?Hn<mM3U5I]I7;=00i9A7\;9iGSM^3@mmJW_APnVA4TSEM@CA6T395F?6F023]A:V6PR=dIfJWH[M[ZN5Cn2lWC^?>731GF@PnJf7:]o]f>A0CQi^OmUSHlKh676Yi>l:KcX[l3JUEROAImGE2`7V6BYKj@a^SBOG35dXQ^58MRR]_ZI9WDodYfC[E<k\XDThbh>a`Sbk]aH>S3Z06YUIFfaGEX:VbfWD<QjO1I9n5XJ3UQmBamL7VV052=_HVLTcYgnZ_ngbI7`WUnhG:1VC`OGi1lg7cMSUR^1RJC788\[MG[feW[:h8g^l]PAm^:E4n6HD\5:EWmhTL>K:@bmF99eV\CeTLC3GNO_UkdI8j`g:m11;?GU>a61i][H5=l3Va^^VjlCoL9<llY391Ka8^YYmiiK5n:M<@V>Af=WKmhjIgHAh>9B58]PC<BLn^V>IGcUY@ViFEPW^2[0\R^1@gLF3PhARoVGGFNXT7Am@3id3`9fLgnEjSJI`lidKoU0@_AUW0U9heC8`Tm12[X18@h3VQOS_a@=WA26:aFZ9o:F2BcOg<mK[gL]RCX7lHJb_>5Im;c0mc_?^Ke=lo^Ik_kQlX175Y[5Do_];EOge2aG1oeU>:Zdo=_6h]5k`0;Sd5QK\3dNN;5PS<c`]?gZINfReR8mkf>74>:8ab]KOS@b1CmXYg@47^ebdm=BHG_eTa]FN`M`LP<WRG7QX<ml\>aYH=d8a_71FTgD4_\^kDcCX?_5dWWMg96Y2MP?D1=hke5X7^WiI<P\ie;R6]VKW[6HioSN>i8X:Lh_IjSAKMo[0J9nOnI[`R2RCS;an^>JUGF:QI[f^82m_L_fM75[6]b<ZNeOG6CH=a=YSYX@fVJ3:IL>77S89ilKnJMY6aJd>jAL5nQ3Z=iHRC`RPEPIW9Z28eDN;ik\S@BiiN=MnhJQY\TLVB8SbVka=fD31dT7_Ye3@@g50^LdZ^mRGd0@N@TM1[6WMTfbjo6Ljcf9;Zd`FkF693T6ObP_4J:YGIM]LTRI?hHj?^D;^Ck@4^h_>9:o5H<Vk=9JBdEl[CP>Sk1^I?hlZ\TOFeBdNn`[U\jo1217G5V;93]To6l0?V`B2c9dCLOdi:NNllm12_`0D^Y?8eIPACP:=Y1NY@c6VN\TUgUm84El>D8JKG4cmL^:]lR9@R\d08DKWQ4n2d5l9be0b8LROnjoaWQlm1McV1bhK@Z_O<:H]V[LDi[_OjFEZJ66LQ:0[<>de_5m6n1]ofmV\H9ba1W]\ES4XlRP`S;?c=@7cV7S<K^HVVEGm4:A1ORHBDAl7CRZJLZShZ7j>G7VZZnEAembXCSoIPc=>IfkO_FJdOKUXQaaA8]foY73=MakFlkH5G?:mCbOkI:cQBFP`Fg1U7T4g0A>Qh]:lIe\CTO@;ko;DeSFW44g9lO[leg95fIYP<a6_GZblHRo=?LXcRlWoNI7_<CXBI5an\bH7?MiMNI9jAF<C\`fMm@Y7AbGlaKc2V>GfUUAC8_j9o^Q]U^4f8@g61bS]<M]\cVY67lBlcQ@2F0K0G^:?N:K0b7PlPX\bBYDdkdHU^11LeeClTWUk?7B]>bLkYo]@Ge^g=l<K2gdNIW48Abc6\l8cK57C_o^X\5:ZPFO3il0^L<c5DODV2jGeS4]8I<n[17nP5AcAM?P8XMIcglHJaecmGMAjh?O]78^?\GLfA@5ZFXc\hleWLF\nPfQdLQVA?:HR5C7YK68\>]AOk_Q^f2gBLWb[KJPOU51CL<g2XLJj9f^MPC1CU1dboHPSICdInmFOhZ7HXB^RO2:JWSK]IQF7=fVl50;>n[\7aSZaZaJXW5e@1mJLh_TkAG]Jdmd^J2RX?C2J6^Kf?JF5>Q@jSFnc2SK\:B[Pmg2?lc0]bfM2f3F>J2Z8T<X<[>NLQFgk3[;c6Hl<Pg[Y81<iJKRLMJZoa@]aNROAHXF_OY^Z]R2gg=UZAf8F\l3>bJ<Hb1_?:JHK5gLWGm562lnQ8^7DngehQ_b:0ShOaQ;l4UMUn5BHJJ3O?DX\a4Z9\T5a\^PgR>21_j=Y:Y6_8bjbU[Y\e?NKfeQ1=91lEmLNQPood7P@[kG]3]IAJN[Gc?OOMa[aj<RW=7g7BDNkWi]:o?`i<4L1k?CT>E?WMn?5SkmB_E0f`?DX`^6:BKm[A^KLFgg1]_U`JR^Pj2o\H\g\^=FFNJQ:B07>ZIZAZlH`455@c0J0Eai5KLM>RHBj\>:2Kom3S]\:B9I3EA=@S6>9oNcF^E<kT@6?m^`X=b=gJ@eM\Kb237;CHCH^T`M0;Jfb6Lj[J7m;`5Plj=5?nT4?\cmXb\NnTKB1cM:e@LlM9doYKhae48BXLJoCjGm008NUaiRMT1EM]XCIn\GYHlH`7O7:h0;RAmWfRBU>YYUKT3<L3V4fX\]n7c8SI0A?QF``BMSRoQ>lJYBlViHj_3mNH29b8k17ToWJ6Sch^<G?gLojE;diOJ>6`DkGeYKh22Ron@kbm2eMHPiPLYbH`8\BMdSb44dY?fLjlg^jfdV4I<[0kGAFT2onN][I^iH8Bn^<bZP372I7PH>Lm>h]Fik3^Xj`VDA\PeA^M^T`AESHm>eFfgB4UfC_c<[=m20fZIjHc9RV_eFjQL_4i9:<cE0RCWaKj69hT5O=BPDmWGEl6J`MNUU`ii<79NUEA2VbJ203AEa5VO\_WISlSCMh0IE@R=Mi6fk[l1Q4m6RTJd4:i]JBL2gn1WAIZELQIa44cLV2BSB^=ijGZE0ZbUYckQ]mNJEin@2dA938eBiSKL;^B1`1IHnfQkLZ5SZ_;9[AMD4Ci=:
```

Hope this helps.